# What do setting CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled from defaults actually do?

Tags: macos, display, catalina, font

I was trying to make fonts on external non-retina display look good and I was playing with setting `CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled` as many advices on the internet said. But nothing helped me and I declined an idea of using an external display.

But now I wonder what this setting actually does? I was playing with `CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled` on my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) with Catalina and without external display and it seems to me that this setting does not change how the fonts are rendered on built-in dislay. No noticeable difference.

Can somebody please explain what setting `CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled` is supposed to do? Maybe I use it wrong or not able to see the difference.

Comment: In short: Nothing. Apple have disabled the difference.

Comment: @benwiggy for Catalina I suppose?

Answer (score 4):

`CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled` is used to enable/disable subpixel antialiasing. Apple disabled it automatically on macOS Mojave which may cause problems on some displays (especially non-LCD) but it improves the rendering on Retina screens.

Here is an example :

[image: With/Without]

Comment: Thank you for showing a visual difference. But what about Catalina?